# Faithfully flat checkable on finitely generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, tensor-products

A left $R$-module $_RM$ is said to be faithfully flat if it is flat and, for any $N_R$, $N \otimes_R M = 0$ implies $N = 0$. I would like to show that $M$ is faithfully flat if it is flat and, for any **finitely generated** $N_R$, $N \otimes_R M = 0$ implies $N = 0$.

My proof of this goes as follows. Let $N_R$ be an arbitrary $R$-module with $N \otimes_R M = 0$. $N$ is the direct limit of its finitely generated submodules $N_\alpha$ (ordered by inclusion)[1]. And tensor product commutes with direct limit[2], so

$0 =  N \otimes_R M = (\lim N_\alpha) \otimes_R M = \lim (N_\alpha \otimes_R M)$. So each $N_\alpha \otimes_R M = 0$, so by assumption, each $N_\alpha = 0$, and so $N = \lim N_\alpha = 0$.

Is this right? I guess now I've written it down, the most questionable line is the claim that $\lim (N_\alpha \otimes_R M) = 0$ implies $N_\alpha \otimes_R M = 0$ $\forall \alpha$ - i.e. that the direct limit of non-zero modules is non-zero.

References:
[1] http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/direct-limit-of-modules-pt-ii/

[2] http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/tensor-products-naturally-commute-with-direct-limits/

Comment: It is not true that the direct limit of non-zero modules is non-zero: take, for instance, a vector space $V$ with an endomorphism $\alpha$ such that, for each $v \in V$ there is an $n$ with $\alpha^n (v) = 0$; then the direct limit of $V \to V \to V \to V \to \cdots$ is zero. _However_ if you know that the transitions in your directed system are injective homomorphisms, then the direct limit contains all the objects as submodules.